# Converting from awkward arrays into torch arrays

Tags: pytorch, awkward-array

Note: I am using awkward version 1.10.3.

So, the general overview is that I have a set of data that is in awkward arrays, and I want to be able to pass this data to a simple feedforward pytorch model. I believe that pytorch doesn't natively handle awkward arrays so I am planning on converting the data to either torch or numpy arrays before passing through to the model. I should also note that whilst the data is stored in awkward arrays, at this point the data is *not* jagged.

Here is an example of the input data and of what I am looking for:

```
import awkward as ak
import numpy as np
import torch


arr = ak.Array({"MET_pt" : [0.0, 100.0, 20.0, 30.0, 4.0],
                 "MET_phi" : [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
                 "class" : [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]})

# These are my input features
x = arr[['MET_pt', 'MET_phi']]
# These are my class labels
y = arr['class']
#
## Here would be the code converting to torch tensors 
# 
x_torch = torch.tensor([[0, 0], [100, 0.1], [20, 0.2], [30, 0.3], [4, 0.4]])

y_torch = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

However, I cannot find an easy way to convert x from the awkward arrays to the torch arrays.
I can easily convert y to torch tensors by simply doing:

```
torch.tensor(y)
> tensor([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

But I am unable to do this for the x array:

```
torch.tensor(x)
> TypeError: object of type 'Record' has no len()
```

This lead me to the idea of converting to numpy arrays first:

```
torch.tensor(ak.to_numpy(x))
> TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.void. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool
```

But as you can see this doesn't work either.

I think the problem lies in the fact that the ak.to_numpy() function converts the x array to:

```
ak.to_numpy(x)
> array([(  0., 0. ), (100., 0.1), ( 20., 0.2), ( 30., 0.3), (  4., 0.4)],
      dtype=[('MET_pt', '<f8'), ('MET_phi', '<f8')])
```

where I want it to convert like:

```
ak.to_numpy(x)

> [[0, 0], [100, 0.1], [20, 0.2], [30, 0.3], [4, 0.4]]
```

Is there anyway of converting an N-dim non-jagged awkward array such as x into the format shown immediately above? Or is there a smarter way to convert directly to torch tensors?

Sorry if this is a stupid question! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to convert it to a list of dictionaries using `to_list()`, and then read out the numerical values. Converting it directly using `to_numpy()` seems to result in the keys being tied up in the dtypes, which is why I opted for `to_list()`.

```
#Read out the values from each dictionary entry in arr.to_list()
arr_dicts = arr.to_list()
arr_dict_values = [list(arr_dict.values()) for arr_dict in arr_dicts]

#To numpy
arr_np = np.array(arr_dict_values)

#To float32 tensor. Could supply "arr_np" or "arr_dict_values" here.
arr_t = torch.tensor(arr_dict_values).float()

#Slice out X and y tensors
x_t = arr_t[:, 0:2]
y_t = arr_y[:, 2]
```

Comment: Ideally, you want to avoid converting compact, efficient, array-like data into Python objects as an intermediate step.

Comment: I agree. Initially I tried working with `.to_numpy()` to convert directly into a numpy array, but the result had custom dtypes that I couldn't cast to a float using `.astype()`.

Answer (score 1):

You've already converted `y`; the problem with `x` is that it's not a purely numerical array. You could convert `x` to a [NumPy structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html),

```py
>>> ak.to_numpy(x)
array([(  0., 0. ), (100., 0.1), ( 20., 0.2), ( 30., 0.3), (  4., 0.4)],
      dtype=[('MET_pt', '<f8'), ('MET_phi', '<f8')])
```

which can then be viewed and reshaped to get the array that you want:

```py
>>> ak.to_numpy(x).view("<f8").reshape(-1, 2)
array([[  0. ,   0. ],
       [100. ,   0.1],
       [ 20. ,   0.2],
       [ 30. ,   0.3],
       [  4. ,   0.4]])
```

but this relies strongly on the fact that all of the fields are the same type, `"<f8"` (doubles). If you had a mix of floating-point numbers and integers (charge?), or numbers of different bit-widths, then this wouldn't work.

Here's a better method: break up `x` (or the original `arr`) into its two fields, first.

```py
>>> x["MET_pt"]
<Array [0, 100, 20, 30, 4] type='5 * float64'>
>>> x["MET_phi"]
<Array [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4] type='5 * float64'>
```

What you want to do is interleave these so that you get one value from `"MET_pt"`, followed by one value from `"MET_phi"`, then the next value from `"MET_pt"`, and so on. If you first put the values in length-1 lists, which is a reshaping (can be done in Awkward or NumPy, with the same syntax),

```py
>>> x["MET_pt", :, np.newaxis]
<Array [[0], [100], [20], [30], [4]] type='5 * 1 * float64'>
>>> x["MET_phi", :, np.newaxis]
<Array [[0], [0.1], [0.2], [0.3], [0.4]] type='5 * 1 * float64'>
```

then what you want is to concatenate each of these length-1 lists from the first array with each of the length-1 lists from the second array. That is, you want to concatenate them, not concatenation at `axis=0`, but concatenation at `axis=1`, the first level deep of lists (see [ak.concatenate](https://awkward-array.org/doc/main/reference/generated/ak.concatenate.html) or [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)).

```py
>>> np.concatenate((x["MET_pt", :, np.newaxis], x["MET_phi", :, np.newaxis]), axis=1)
<Array [[0, 0], [100, 0.1], ..., [30, ...], [4, 0.4]] type='5 * 2 * float64'>
```

Now you can pass it to Torch.

```py
>>> torch.tensor(np.concatenate((
...     x["MET_pt", :, np.newaxis], x["MET_phi", :, np.newaxis]
... ), axis=1))
tensor([[  0.0000,   0.0000],
        [100.0000,   0.1000],
        [ 20.0000,   0.2000],
        [ 30.0000,   0.3000],
        [  4.0000,   0.4000]], dtype=torch.float64)
```